# Android Spinner style top divider

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, spinner, android-theme, android-styles

I'm trying to change the style for the Spinner's top divider, but without success.

I can only get that to work:
http://s18.postimg.org/qbg7920mh/spinner.png

Is is possible? What item should I modify?

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!--item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem</item-->
    <!--item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerDropDownItem</item-->
    <!--item name="android:dropDownItemStyle">@style/TestSpinnerItemStyle</item-->
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/TestSpinnerStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="TestSpinnerItemStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:divider">#00b54a</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">5dp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

By looking at your code, there must be an obvious error!
Rename TestSpinnerItemStyle to TestSpinnerStyle in second part like:

```
<style name="TestSpinnerStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.ListView.DropDown">
...
</style>
```